# Load multiple sheets to MySQL from Excel using VBA on button click

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets that I need to be able upload to a MySQL database with a single button click.

Issue 1 - Each sheet has different columns Headers
Issue 2 - Each Sheet also has different # of columns
Issue 3 - Each Sheet also has a different # of rows

I started out thinking the following:

```
Private Sub Export_Click()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=<server>;DATABASE=<db>;USER=<user>;PASSWORD=<password>;"

Dim rng As Range

s8columns = "(<28 columns>)"

s9columns = "(<40 columns>)"

s10columns = "(<10 Columns>)"

s12columns = "(<15 Columns>)"

s13columns = "(<18 Columns>)"

s14columns = "(<6 Columns>)"

Sheetcolumns = Array(s8columns, s9columns, s10columns, s12columns, s13columns, s14columns)
Datasheets = Array(Sheet8.Name, Sheet9.Name, Sheet10.Name, Sheet12.Name, Sheet13.Name, Sheet14.Name)

For i = LBound(Datasheets) To UBound(Sheetcolumns)
    colnum = Worksheets(Datasheets(i)).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Sqlp1 = "INSERT INTO " & Datasheets(i) & " " & Sheetcolumns(i) & " values('"
    For n = 1 To colnum
        Sqlp2 = Sqlp1 & Row.Cells(n).Value
    Next n
    Sql = Sqlp2 & "')"
    Worksheets(Sheet15.Name).Range("A1") = Sql
    With Worksheets(Datasheets(i))
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        For Each Row In rng.Rows
            con.Execute Sql
        Next Row
    End With
Next i
con.Close
End Sub
```

I am stuck on how I can append & Row.cells(n).Value for each column in the current sheet to the Sql query.  You can make up whatever column names you need, I can't give them.

Edit:

Let me show a good insert statement to help layout the issue better

INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) VALUES('ABC','123','1900-01-01',12)

For my current query the Array for the columns on each sheet is the Column List.  The trouble I am having is how I can get the VALUES() piece dynamically based on the number of columns and each value in those columns in the sheet.

Edit 2:

```
For i = LBound(Datasheets) To UBound(Sheetcolumns)
    With Worksheets(Datasheets(i))
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        numcol = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For Each Row In rng.Rows
            valuesArray = Range("A" & rng.Row & ":" & (Col_Letter(numcol)) & rng.Row).Value
            'Sql = "INSERT INTO " & Datasheets(i) & " " & Sheetcolumns(i) & " values('" & valuesArray & "')"
            MsgBox (Join(valuesArray(), "','"))
            'con.Execute
        Next Row
    End With
Next i
con.Close
```

I am now trying to populate an Array from the row of data values in the column.  I am still running into issues though.  I can't seem to get it to build each column in the row into the array and then join it.

Comment: Are all of your table fields text datatype?  I'd be inclined to drive this from a worksheet containing a couple of metadata tables (1) table id, source sheet name, destination tablename (2) table id, source column name/number, destination field name, destination datatype.  This type of information is much easier to manage in a worksheet than it is when mixed into your VBA.

Comment: Mixed, some numbers, some dates, and some varchar. As for driving them from a worksheet - can you provide an example?  I am not sure I get how this helps me make the SQL query.

Comment: @TimWilliams I suppose I just don't understand how making a worksheet that has all the same stuff as the Arrays helps me change the number of columns used in the SQL query and add the &row.cells(n).Value in a dynamic way.

Comment: I realized I am being dumb about this.  I merely need to populate an array for each row with the correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the loop with the Array:

```
    For i = LBound(Datasheets) To UBound(Sheetcolumns)
    With Worksheets(Datasheets(i))
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        numcol = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For Each Row In rng.Rows
            valuesArray = Worksheets(Datasheets(i)).Range("A" & rng.Row & ":" & (Col_Letter(numcol)) & rng.Row).Value
            insertValues = Join2D(valuesArray, "','")
            Sql = "INSERT INTO colocar." & Datasheets(i) & Sheetcolumns(i) & "VALUES('" & insertValues & "')"
        Worksheets(Sheet2.Name).Range("A100") = Sql
            'con.Execute Sql
        Next Row
    End With
Next i
```

Still Troubleshooting why it errors on execution for the SQL.